# Spring boot and apache spark - container conflict

Tags: maven, tomcat, apache-spark, spring-boot

I am trying to use spring boot 1.1.5 and apache spark 1.0.2 together in project. Look like apache spark uses Jetty container internally and I have configured spring-boot to use Tomcat container. However application startup fails with some securityException at root cause. If I see full stack trace looks like spring boot trying to initialize "jettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory" which it shouldn't in first place. It probably picks it up from classpath due to jetty presence via spark. If I exclude jetty from spark and run again I don't see same error again but then SparkContext initialization fails due to not finding jetty. How do i tell spring-boot runtime to look for "TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory" instead of jetty one?

Comment: might want to include the full stacktrace on what you see. also some examples of how you have configured spark and spring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Joakim Erdfelt, Thanks. 
I was just waiting to see if someone is familiar with this situation and if it's just a small configuration change. As it turns out it is! 
 
 @Configuration 
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={EmbeddedServletContainerFactory.class}) 
public class MyConfiguration { }

I defined my own "EmbeddedServletContainerFactory" bean as a "org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContaine‌​rFactory" and it started working as I expected.

Answer (score 9):

I got "java.lang.SecurityException: class "javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionIdListener"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package"

To fix this issue I was need to remove all *javax.servlet* dependencies.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.servlet</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.orbit</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.servlet</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you! This solved many hours of time searching for the answer.