# Spring Boot and Apache Spark Security Exception: signer mismatch

Tags: java, spring, gradle, apache-spark, spring-boot

Solving one problem led to the next, now I am getting an error about a mismatching signer. Please see below:

Here is my original gradle build file:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.3.3.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}") 
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'  
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

jar {
    baseName = 'appTest'
    version = '1.0.0'
}
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')

    //compile 'org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.11:1.4.0' //problem here

    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    compile("com.h2database:h2")
    compile('mysql:mysql-connector-java')

    testCompile("junit:junit")
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testCompile("junit:junit")
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.9'
}
```

If I try and build without adding the dependency `compile 'org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.11:1.4.0'` it runs. however, if I try and run it with that dependency I get:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.

SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/xxx/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.16/54c6dd23a7c420e40b8848e962d5f2a3534260af/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.16.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]

SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/xxx/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/1.1.5/92353eb144695bba80b31f7bec4f36d871f230ac/logback-classic-1.1.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
```

Researching, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14024756/slf4j-class-path-contains-multiple-slf4j-bindings). I then tried to exclude `slf4j-log4j12` by adding below (just above my `jar{...}` in my gradle build file):

```
configurations.all {
    exclude module: 'slf4j-log4j12'
}
```

Which actually builds. However, when I try and run it via `bootRun` I get another error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: class "javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionIdListener"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
```

I assume this is due to multiple jar's being used which have different signatures? How do I solve this? Please help!

For full error, [view here.](https://gist.github.com/gudthing/567d008ce167f3b9f32eaa3213ba0d8a)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I think I may have solved it. I do need to run some further tests.

On investigation, it appeared that spark is configured [to run on Jetty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28820250/spring-boot-and-apache-spark-container-conflict), not Tomcat. Looking at the log file, I could see it was trying to work with Jetty.

I looked in dependencies, and found a `org.eclipse.jetty.orbit`. I've managed to exclude it by adding below to the `configurations.all`

```
exclude module: 'javax.servlet'
```